# Is it possible to prevent direct interaction with the smart contract from other GUIs?

Tags: contract-development

This may sound dumb, but I'm curious if there's a way to make sure that only the Frontend of the Dapp can interact with the smart contract. Otherwise, direct writing from Etherscan or Remix causes a lot of edge cases to handle, for example validations of data inputs are done in frontend, whereas on-chain that would require a lot of gas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible, the contract and it's external/public functions will be available to the whole network when once you deploy it.

I think if you don't verify your contract's code and don't expose them on your front end, no one will know about the functions names. Still, it is very bad practice.

If you have some functions that should not be executed by other people. You can check if the sender is the contract owner and if not, revert.

Like:

```
function important(){
 require(msg.sender == owner,"you are not owner");
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess in my case the question is about the data inputs. In frontend, I am able to do the necessary validations for the data off-chain, whereas if contract is interacted via Etherscan without those validations, a lot of edge cases will appear.

Comment: I think you need an oracle, here is a good tutorial to get started https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/ethereum-oracle-contracts-tutorial-pt1